# Does the name length for an attribute / method add runtime to a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Meaning can I name my methods and attributes as long (and descriptive) as I want, or should I make an effort to make them as concise and short as possible for the sake of runtime.

Comment: Make them descriptive. The time saved on modern architectures by cutting a few bytes from a method/attribute name is so incredibly miniscule as to be nonexistant.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of a method name affects only the parser for the interpreter.  The time to read the characters and build the string is insignificant compared to the run time of the program.  You should use meaningful names: *any* time a human spends in interpreting the method name will be more than the microseconds lost in execution.

Comment: @MattDMo I'm allowing for a massive quantity of executions.
A single read of extra characters from an external medium will be in the nanosecond magnitude ... but we're working on that :-)

Comment: To be clear, the parser isn't even involved once the program gets running; for some names (e.g. local variable names) the string isn't used at all (the emitted bytecode contains the numeric index that name was mapped to at compile time), and for others (globals, attribute access) it is looked up using the string, but all such strings are interned, and the lookup is performed in a `dict` of purely interned strings, so the *contents* of the strings are never compared; interned strings are compared solely by identity, the value stored in the string is never even looked at.

Answer (score 0):

The length of the name doesn't affect the runtime or memory consumption, it all depends on the value of the attribute